# Let $G$ a group of order $n$. If $k$ divide $n$ in a certain sense, is there an element of order $k$.

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ a group of order $n$. I was wondering that if $k$ divide $n$ in a certain sense, then there an element of order $k$. I explain. Let $g$ an element of order $m$. We know by Lagrange that $m\mid n$. Then, if $k\mid m$, do we have an element of order $k$ ? To me it's true. Indeed, since $g$ is of order $m$, then $\left<g\right>=\{1,g,...,g^{m/k},...,g^{m-1}\}$, and then, $g^{m/k}$ is an element of order $k$. Is it true ?

Comment: If $G$ is nilpotent, then yes.  Otherwise, no.  The alternating group $A_4$ has no element of order $4$.

Comment: @MSE Don't blame other people if you are not clear about what you mean by "in a certain sense."  You are the one who has to clarify.  If your "in a certain sense" means "when there always exists an element of order $k\mid n$," then what you ask is vacuously true.

Comment: @Batominovski: I don't blame anyone. I just specified the "certain sense" in the post, so read the title only is not enough to answer my question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes your reasoning is right, any cyclic group of order $m$ has a unique subgroup of order $k$ whenever $k \mid m$. And since $k \mid m \mid n$, we have $k \mid n$.